# What is the proper use of the anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I've read how the anchor tag is holy, it should not be used with javascript:

`<a href="javascript:(alert('no!'))">Popup</a>`

that it should **ONLY** be used for a link to another page:

`<a href="/grassIsAlwaysGreener.html">Take me over there</a>`

So what is the proper use of the anchor tag with javascript?  Should I be using:

`<a href="#" onclick="someJsFn();">Energize!</a>`

or some other variant? I'm somewhat confused by different views on the subject. Also is it only SEO that I should be worried about if making the `href` a javascript piece? Or is it more of a proper web standards compliance deal?

Thoughts? Hopefully I'm not the only one confused.

Comment: @Jakub Check out "unobtrusive JavaScript" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript. You bind a click handler to the ANCHOR element via JavaScript. For example, using jQuery: `$("a").click(function() { /* click handler */ });`

Comment: @Šime that would be a worthy answer, it's all there's to say really

Comment: @Jakub btw, you have a syntax error in your code. This is how it should be written: `<a href="javascript:alert('no!');">Popup</a>`

Comment: what if I am generating a page full of javascript links that might have different uses? I'm just playing devils advocate here...

Comment: @Pekka btw, Pekka, I recently noticed, you are the only person on Stack Overflow with a CSS gold badge :)

Comment: @Šime Vidas thanks, corrected

Comment: @Šime yeah, that one was really a nice thing to get! :) Bobince will soon join the club, too. @Jakub then you would give each link an ID and address each separately: `$("a#clickbutton").click(...)` as long as the ID makes sense (i.e. is descriptive of what the function does) it will work fine without confusion

Comment: @Jakub You bind the click handers for the anchors based on either their class ( `$("a.external")` ), their position in the DOM ( `$("#nav a")` ), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone Jakub; even the biggest WWW companies use different approaches.

However based on experiences since Netscape days I wouldn't use :

```
<a href="javascript:(alert'no!')">Popup</a>
```

which can make some troubles on some browsers, like opening an empty page or breaking the event order on the current page.

However;

```
<a href="#" onclick="someJsFn();">Energize!</a>
```

or;

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>
```

don't make a serious trouble and are ok to use. Note that the prior one may reset the scroll to the top.

You should use meaningful link targets and unobtrusive javascript wherever possible, but this is not always possible in real life examples. It's not a defined standard, but a method highly agreed by most of the web developers.

When it comes to standards, there is one related with this situation:

You should consider using a 'button' for inputs which doesn't really send the visitor to a page, but does an operation. This is also important for SEO.

Comment: They **can** make a serious trouble. For example, if you decide to change the name of the function in your JavaScript file, and this file is used by multiple web-pages with multiple anchors referencing it, you have to manually rename all those references in all the anchors in all those web-pages, which is frustrating (if nothing else).

Comment: @Šime Vidas : I see it as a subject of usability, like using external JS rather than embedded JS. As I stated, 'a' tags should have targets wherever possible, however this is not mostly possible in situations where the link is used as a button, which casts an action. I vote for the usage of 'buttons' in this situation, where possible.

Comment: Aha, you meant "they don't make trouble" as in browsers interpret them correctly. However, for the web-developer they can be troublesome.

Comment: @Šime Vidas : Ah, right, the preference depends on the situation. Like there is no need for an external JS file for a single-line function which appears on just one page which will stay online for 1 month and won't ever be updated. So I'm keeping the management schema out of the scope. But I prefer using external unobtrusive JS for web applications. =)

Answer (score 1):

As @Sime says (and it should be an answer really), it is considered "bad practise" to now directly reference javascript in any HTML object.  So in these cases you attach the event using something like jQuery using the concepts laid out in "unobtrusive javascript".

As you mention another consideration is SEO and accessibility.  If SEO is important to your site, make sure that the site is fully navigable using just standard links.  Again you can manage this using "unobtrusive javascript", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've always gone with using an anchor as normal (i.e. specify either an alternate url that is another location where the user could perform what's being done through javascript, or use  `javascript:void()` / `#`) then use the onclick event for anything you want executed.

You could also use a `<span>` if you're that worried about conformance, just would need to perhaps style it (change cursor, perhaps color as well) to make it visually obvious you're making it an action.

I think Facebook is the best-case example. Almost all of their links are javascript tied in, but they also have a "backup" page for those that either have disallowed javascript or don't have it (the later, in this day and age, being far less common). Take a look at a module that reacts like you'd like yours to and see how they've done it. They also invested a bunch of work in best-practices that you can benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, you should bind your anchor links to javascript methods only by using unobtrusive javascript like [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385544/paul-hadfield) mentioned.

This means, using separation of concerns and leaving your markup being just that, html markup:

```
<a id="Jolter">Energize!</a>
```

and later

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Jolter").click(function(){
            // doStuffHere ...
        });
    });
</script>
```